# Calculate duration with php

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am using following code to get time difference.It is ok for most case.But When the start time is 12:00 PM and end time is 1:30 PM,it show 11.0 instead of 1:30 as a result. The start and end time come from mysql.

```
$startTime=new DateTime(date("h:i",strtotime($data['start_time'])));
$endTime=new DateTime(date("h:i",strtotime($data['end_time'])));
$timeInterval=$startTime->diff($endTime);
$getHours=$timeInterval->format('%h');
$getMinutes=$timeInterval->format('%i');
$duration=$getHours.":".$getMinutes;
```

Help me,plz.
Thanks.

Comment: Do not use `date('h:i')` then, is eliminates the AM/PM distinction. you _could_ use `date('H:i')`, but better yet, assuming you have a sane `TIME` or `DATETIME` column, just feed the raw `$data['start_time']` into `DateTime`'s constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to change `h:i` to `H:i`:

```
<?php
$startTime=new DateTime(date("H:i",strtotime('12:00')));
$endTime=new DateTime(date("H:i",strtotime('13:30')));
$timeInterval=$startTime->diff($endTime);
$getHours=$timeInterval->format('%h');
$getMinutes=$timeInterval->format('%i');
$duration=$getHours.":".$getMinutes;
echo $duration;
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/VSijTI)

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps:

```
$differenceMinutes  = (strtotime($data['end_time']) - strtotime($data['start_time'])) / 60; // Get difference as minutes
$getHours           = floor($differenceMinutes / 60); // Get hours
$getMinutes         = floor($differenceMinutes % 60); // Get minutes
$duration           = $getHours . " h " . $getMinutes . " min";

print $duration; // Print it out!
```